# Consulta con GROUP BY MYSQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo esta tabla

```
  id   departure    value          date 
1065 | 2018-09-20 | 10490 | 2018-09-20 18:04:19 |
1034 | 2018-09-25 | 10582 | 2018-09-20 18:04:19 |
1035 | 2018-09-25 | 13096 | 2018-09-20 19:05:19 |
```

Y esta consulta

```
SELECT * FROM departures GROUP BY departure
```

Pero al hacer GROUP BY da este resultado:

```
  id   departure    value          date 
1065 | 2018-09-20 | 10490 | 2018-09-20 18:04:19 |
1034 | 2018-09-25 | 10582 | 2018-09-20 18:04:19 |
```

Necesito que al hacer GROUP BY traiga el registro mas reciente del campo departure según el campo date y no el primero. Es decir debería quedar en value 13096 y no 10582. No puedo tener más de un registro por fecha en el campo departure.

No puedo usar subconsultas.

Agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Si el `id` es la `pk` de la tabla y lo puedes usar para determinar la última fila por cada grupo, una forma sencilla podría ser:

```
SELECT  D.id,
        D.departure,
        D.value,
        D.date
    FROM  departure D
    INNER JOIN (SELECT departure, 
                       max(ID) 'MaxId'
            FROM departures 
            GROUP BY departure
        ) M
        ON M.MaxId = D.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Según como veo el ejercicio, no debes usar un **GROUP BY**, a menos que desees usar un función como **SUM, MAX, MIN**, etc. Si lo que quieres es ordenar de forma descendente un campo, lo que debes hacer es usar **ORDER BY** al fnal de la consulta, adjuntando el *[campo]* mas la palabra **DESC**. En tu caso:

```
SELECT*
FROM departures
ORDER BY departure DESC
```

**EDICION**

En caso de no tener que repetir los **departure**, usa **DISTINCT** en vez de **GROUP BY**, de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT DISTINCT departure -- sigues agregando aquí los campos.
FROM departures
ORDER BY departure DESC
```

Pruebalo y cuentanos como te fue. Saludos.

Comment: No se pueden repetir las fechas de departure, tengo dos del 2018-09-25 por esa razón uso el GROUP BY. Gracias

Comment: Gracias por tus aportes, intente con el DISTINCT pero la consulta solo me devuelve el campo departure tengo entendido que para que me devuelva todos los datos de mi tabla debo hacer una subconsulta y no las puedo usar.

Comment: Por eso en la linea de las columnas te comenté, "sigues agregando aquí los campos", solo sigue poniendo los campos que estés necesitando y el DISTINCT hará el trabajo, buscará lo registros únicos de las columnas que especifiques, saludos!

Comment: Si lo hice como escribiste, pero al poner SELECT DISTINCT departure, id me trae los 3 registros nuevamente, no los agrupa

Comment: Claro, porque el campo "id" tiene diferentes registros, es por ello que el conjunto de esas columnas, implica la repetición del "departure", con el group by te va apasar igual, y el subselect resultará en lo mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es que te traiga el valor mas reciente lo que necesitas hacer es esto,

```
SELECT id,departure,value,date
FROM departures
GROUP BY id,departure,value,date 
ORDER BY departure, value  DESC
```

Comment: No se pueden repetir las fechas de departure, tengo dos del 2018-09-25 por esa razón uso el GROUP BY. Gracias

Comment: Pero puede dar la casualidad de que el value sea diferente en la misma fecha entonces, no veo la necesidad, porque te va a generar un campo fecha con la misma

Comment: Es una tabla que genera varios registros al día por esa razón se repite la fecha en departure, por esa razón necesito tomar el último registro del día

Comment: Bueno pero si es con el mismo valué entonces estas en lo correcto

Comment: Hay que agregarle el group by entonces

Comment: Edite la pregunta de como quedaria si es asi como me comentaste

Answer (score 0):

Podrías aplicarle la función Max(departure)

```
select id,max(departure),value,date 
from departures GROUP BY departure
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con :

`SELECT * FROM departures GROUP BY departure ORDER BY date desc;`

(sino prueba con `asc`), ya me dices, saludos.

Comment: no resultará por que el orden solo lo hará en los dos value resultantes pero ella necesita el value 13096